# Do I have to replace junction box to replace outside 4” ultra thin led lights?

Tags: led, junction-box, connectors

I got 4” Led lights outside my home. I have 6 lights out and I am having a hard time find the right connectors for jbox. I need 3 male connectors for jbox but can’t seem to find. Is this possible or do the joboxes need to be replaced?

[image]

Comment: Why do you need male connectors?  If the light is bad and you get a replacement it will already have a connector.   What are you doing?   Also ... why do you have six lights out?  That's unusual.  Before you replace them you should figure that out.

Answer (score 3):

Each Ultra thin LED should have an accompanying driver/ j/box.

If you are trying to connect new light to older driver boxes, they may not match.

It is highly unlikely that 6 lights would go out at the same time.  You would be better off checking the wiring in the boxes.  A bad connection in one box can cause all the lights downstream to be out.